# Is this is a sound way of proving an inequality?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Prove the following statement: ∀a > 0, ∃x ∈ ℝ such that (x+cosx)a > 3

x+cosx > 3/a

Since x + cosx can be any real number, it can just be a number greater than 3/a.

Is this reasoning sound?

Comment: I think you are confusing sound and valid.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm rather new to proofs in general. If you don't mind me asking, what's the difference between sound and valid in logic?

Comment: valid assumes the premise is true and comes up with a truth value of the conclusion ( aka if the premises are true the conclusion is true), sound has proven premises. https://www.khanacademy.org/partner-content/wi-phi

Comment: Going by that, would my proof be sound since the premise regarding the range of x+cosx is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea but "$x+\cos(x)$ can be any real number" is not incredibly precise. The idea is that we have the following nice bounds from the triangle inequality:
$$
|x|-|\cos(x)|\leq |x+\cos(x)|\leq |x|+|\cos(x)|
$$
Using the fact that $0\leq|\cos(x)|\leq 1,$
we know that 
$$
|x|-1\leq |x+\cos(x)|\leq |x|+1
$$
And thus in particular if we choose $x>\frac{3}{a}+1$, the desired inequality will hold.

Comment: Could you go more into detail about the triangle inequality? I'm having trouble understanding its purpose.

Comment: @James The triangle inequality in general or the specific application here?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the triangle inequality in general, is its application here to prove that x + cosx has a range of any real number?

Comment: @James The triangle inequality is a staple for introductory analysis and estimation techniques. The simplified version is that if $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, then $|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$. Applying this to $|(a+b)-b|$ gives $|a|-|b|\leq |a+b|$. So thus we have the bound $|a|-|b|\leq |a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$. Above I have set $a=x$ and $b=\cos(x)$ to show that $x+\cos(x)$ must grow to infinity; in particular, it must eventually be greater than $3/a$

Comment: But how does the bound prove that x + cos(x) can be any number? Sorry if i'm missing something here :/

Comment: On it's own it doesn't do that, but it does show that the limit as $x$ goes to infinity is infinity, and as $x$ goes to negative infinity it goes to negative infinity. You can then invoke continuity and the intermediate value theorem to show that $x+\cos(x)$ maps surjectively to $\mathbb{R}$.